Dividing up a solid volume into smaller particles and calculating total surface area
This seems like an easy question to answer: Would dividing up a solid volume into spheres or cubes yield a higher total particle surface area? My intuition tells me that because spheres have a different surface area to volume ratio, they would provide a different total surface area than cubes. However, when I do the calculations, all spherical or all cube particles yield the same surface area. Why is this? Is my math wrong? The following is my method of solving this problem:

Suppose you have a solid cube that is $1m\times1m\times1m$ with a total volume $V_{Tot}=1m^{3}$
I want to divide up this cube into tiny pieces, and then calculate the total surface area of the smaller pieces.
Suppose I melt this large volume cube and reform it into small spheres or cubes.
I can calculate the total surface area of the small particles (spheres or cubes) by using the following equations.
$\frac{V_{Tot}}{V_{particle}} = N_{particles}$  , the number of particles.
Then I can multiply the surface area of an individual particle $a_{particle}$ by the number of particles $N_{particles}$ to get the total surface area of all particles, $A_{particles}$.
For cubes of 500µm side length, the equation would be:
$N_{cubes}\times a_{cube} = N_{cubes}\times6(500\times10^{-6}m)^2$
For spheres of 500µm diameter, the equation would be:
$N_{spheres}\times a_{sphere} = N_{spheres}\times4\pi(\frac{500}{2}\times10^{-6}m)^2$
When I follow this process for spheres with diameters of 500µm and cubes of side length 500µm, I end up obtaining the same total surface area $A_{particles}$ for all the particles, whether I am forming all tiny spheres or all tiny cubes.
TL;DR: Does this make sense that I would get the same surface area whether using spheres or cubes?
Here's the calculation:
For cubes
$\frac{V_{Tot}}{V_{cube}} = N_{cubes} \rightarrow 1m^3/(500\times10^{-6})^3 = 8\times10^9 cubes$
$N_{cubes}\times a_{cube} = 8\times10^9\times6(500\times10^{-6}m)^2 = \color{maroon}{1.2\times10^4m^2}$
For spheres
$\frac{V_{Tot}}{V_{sphere}} = N_{spheres} \rightarrow 1m^3/[(\frac{4}{3}\pi)(\frac{500}{2}\times10^{-6})^3] = 1.5278874536822\times10^{10} spheres$
$N_{spheres}\times a_{sphere} = 1.5\times10^{10}\times4\pi(\frac{500}{2}\times10^{-6}m)^2 = \color{maroon}{1.2\times10^4m^2}$

Total area turns out to be $\displaystyle{6V_{tot}\over\text{diameter}}$ for a sphere and $\displaystyle{6V_{tot}\over\text{edge}}$ for a cube. But that's a mere coincidence, in my opinion.

I did a calculation of "surface area to volume ratios" for both - a sphere of diameter $s$ equal to a cube of edge length $s$ - they come out to be the same, related to what you write here @Intelligentipauca . The result is $\dfrac{6}{s}$.

For any smooth three dimensional object, the area is proportional to the square of a linear dimension and the volume $V$ to the cube of a linear dimension. Thus the area will be proportional to $V^{2/3}$:
$$
A = CV^{2/3}
$$
for a constant $C$ that depends on the shape.
If you cast a unit volume into $N$ similar pieces of volume $1/N$
the total area will be
$$
A = CN(1/N)^{2/3} = CN^{1/3}.
$$
Clearly and unsurprisingly, this grows without bound as $N$ increases.
For the cube, the proportionality constant is $6$. For the sphere it is $\pi^{1/3}6^{2/3} \approx 4.84$. That means breaking into spheres rather than cubes will alway lead to just over $3/4$ of the total area.
In your calculation you have different numbers of cubes and spheres. It's a coincidence that the total areas come out almost the same when you use $500\mu\text{m}$ for both the side of the square and the radius of the cube.

Leaving these previous thoughts in place even though they aren't right. (Several people upvoted it anyway.)
Possible solution too long for a comment.
If you recast the cube into just a single sphere the surface area will decrease. Now see what happens when you recast into two cubes and two spheres. I suspect the spheres will still have smaller area, but not as much smaller (in some appropriate sense).
I think the more particles the smaller the area discrepancy. In your example with many particles the approximation may destroy the inequality.

You had it right the first time. The OP happened to use cubes and spheres of the same inradius, which individually have exactly the same surface-to-volume ratio, for reasons I explain in my answer. But if instead you use an equal number of cubes and spheres, the spheres will always have  about $20%$ less surface area no matter how many there are.

@DavidK I think I had part of it right the first  time, but not all. Your answer and mine make the same point about the proportionality to $N^{1/3}$; yours goes on to address the coincidence the OP found in a beautiful convincing way. I upvoted of course.

The surface to volume ratio is a dimensional quantity.  It has dimension of length$^{-1}$.  While it is true that a sphere has the smallest surface area for a given volume, the surface to volume ratio of a small sphere can be larger than a larger cube.  That is what is going on here. Note that you have more spheres than cubes, which means that the spheres have a smaller volume than the cubes.  The volume difference makes up for the more efficient packing of volume into spheres compared to cubes.

Don't cubes have a more efficient packing volume? They pack without empty space

@I_Don't_Code:  that doesn't matter here.  OP just used the total volume of the starting cube and the volumes of the small pieces.  The small pieces were not packed into anything.

For an appropriate comparison, try melting the original cube down into $8\times10^9$ identical spheres. This makes your spheres actually comparable to the cubes (since they’ll have the same volume for each) and it also saves you from the awkwardness of the leftover $0.822$ sphere.
To find the radius of each sphere, solve for $r$ in
$$
\frac 43 \pi r^3 = (500 \times 10^{-6})^3.
$$
This gives
$r = \frac1{4000}\sqrt[3]{\frac6\pi}$
and the area of each sphere is
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac9{16}\pi}\times10^{-6}\approx1.209\times10^{-6}.$$
So the total surface area of the $8\times10^9$ spheres is approximately $9672,$ which is less than $1.2\times10^4.$

If you compare solids of the same shape but different volumes to each other, the ratio of surface area to volume goes as $1/\sqrt[3]V$ where $V$ is the solid’s volume.
So if you take a cube of volume $1$, which has surface area $6$ (area-to-volume ratio $6$)
and cut it into $8$ cubes of volume $1/8$ each, you get an area-to-volume ratio $1/\sqrt[3]{1/8}=2$ times as large: the area-to-volume ratio is $12.$ Start with a fixed volume; the more pieces you divide it into, keeping the same shape for every piece, the higher the ratio is.
If you compare a sphere to any other solid of the same volume, the sphere will have a smaller surface area. If the other solid has the same surface area, the sphere will have a larger volume.
If on the other hand you choose to compare a sphere with another shape of the same "size" according to some measurement that is neither volume nor surface, the comparisons in the previous paragraph won’t apply, and anything could happen.
In particular, why would you equate the diameter of the sphere with the edge of the cube? Wouldn’t it make more sense to compare the sphere with a cube of equal diameter?
The diameter of your tiny cubes is $0.5\times10^{-3}\sqrt3$.
Try spheres with that diameter and see what area you get.

The peculiar comparison that you chose — to measure the cube by its edge (a property the sphere doesn’t have) — is really a comparison between objects of the same inradius, that is, the same radius sphere can be inscribed in the cube and the sphere. Moreover, all faces of the cube are tangent to its inscribed sphere. This relates to a much more general result, which is that if you take any polyhedron all of whose faces are tangent to the same sphere, if $A$ is the surface area of the polyhedron and $V$ its volume, $V=\frac r3 A,$ where $r$ is the inradius, and this same formula applies also to a sphere (which is a limiting case of polyhedra of this type). The reason is that we can partition the polyhedron into pyramids of height $r,$ and $V=\frac r3 A$ for such pyramids, where $A$ is the base area.
For your calculations, $s=d=2r$ and your observation follows immediately.
This area-volume property holds even in extreme cases such as a square pyramid of side $1$ and height $1000$, which you would think had a terrible area-to-volume ratio. And this pyramid does have a terrible ratio compared to “less pointy” shapes of the same volume or area or diameter. But compared with another shape of the same inradius, the ratio is the same.

Thank you for your thorough response. My motivation is that I'm trying to essentially break up a solid mass into smaller particles, and I was surprised that whether I assumed these particles were simply perfect cubes or spheres of a given size, they had the same surface area overall.

The key assumption is “of a given size”. In fact the spheres are smaller in almost every way. Notice that the sphere fits completely inside the cube but obviously the cube cannot fit inside the sphere. The sphere is smaller in almost every sense I can think of; the only standard measurement that’s the same is the inradius of each shape.

Since volume is the one geometric property you preserve when you break up the mass, wouldn’t “same size” naturally be the same volume?

Spheres actually have a minimum surface area relative to their volume compared to any other geometric solid.  Perfectly symmetrical ("regular") shapes have the largest higher-dimensional quantity relative to their lower-dimensional quantity and the smallest lower-dimensional quantity relative to their higher-dimensional quantity (for example, an equilateral triangle has the largest area relative to its perimeter and the smallest perimeter relative to its area of any triangle, a square has this property out of all quadrilaterals, etc.).  In 3-dimensions, spheres are more symmetrical than cubes because all points on the surface are the same distance (the radius) away from the center.  But in general, yes, breaking a solid into smaller pieces will increase its overall surface area.  That's why cheese in dishes is usually sliced very thin - it allows your tongue to taste more of the cheese flavor while using the same original-sized block of cheese.

What I'm asking is why do sphere and cube particles yield the same surface area overall, even though spheres have the higher "surface area to volume ratio"?

I was wrong: Spheres have the lowest surface area to volume ratio of all solid bodies

Clearly the two solutions approach approximate equality, in part because the geometry allows for almost twice as many spheres as cubes. The problem may be as interesting for the ability to pack so many more spheres in a space as it is for the questions about of surface area.

It doesn't lead to a full number of spheres. I updated my calculation to show it's how many spheres can be made.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
