Surface area to volume ratios equivalent for sphere and cube - why is this?
Suppose I have a cube of side length s and a sphere of diameter s.
Spheres have the smallest surface area to volume ratio of any solid, to my knowledge.
However, when given this setup, the surface area to volume ratios are the same!
Why is this?

Calculation:
Surface area of cube $A_{cube}=6s^2$
Volume of cube $V_{cube}=s^3$
Ratio $A_{cube}/V_{cube}=6s^2/s^3=\color{maroon}{6/s}$
Surface area of sphere $A_{sphere}=4\pi(s/2)^2=\pi s^2$
Volume of sphere $V_{sphere}=\frac{4}{3}\pi(s/2)^3=\frac{\pi}{6}s^3$
Ratio $A_{sphere}/V_{sphere}=\pi s^2/\frac{\pi}{6}s^3=\color{maroon}{6/s}$

This is essentially the same question you asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5007781/dividing-up-a-solid-volume-into-smaller-particles-and-calculating-total-surface, and one of the comments there is an answer: the ratio of surface area to volume is not constant for all spheres. It depends on the radius. The sphere has the minimum surface to area ratio for solids of a given fixed volume.

I appreciate your response @EthanBolker .. I think the answer to this question would help me understand the answer to my other question.

Intuitively, if you cut the pieces smaller, you make more surface area.  A sphere of diameter $s$ has less volume, so is smaller, than a cube of side $s$.

@RossMillikan , so why, in my other question, does the overall surface area balance out to be the same?

Because you have defined the relative sizes of the cube and the sphere in just the ratio that makes the surface to volume the same.  It is not as surprising as it seems because that is a natural definition.

The sphere has the minimum surface to volume ratio for solids of a given fixed volume.
In your calculation the volumes of the cube and the sphere with the particular surface to volume ratio $6/s$ are different. The sphere is much smaller: by a factor of $\pi/6$, so just about half.

"Spheres have the smallest surface area to volume ratio of any solid" is true in some way, but you are getting it wrong. The fact is, for a given volume, the sphere is the shape with the smallest surface area.
Doing the calculations for a volume $1$ cube and sphere,

For a cube, volume $1$ means side length $1$, hence surface area $6$.
For a sphere, volume $1$ means radius $(3/4\pi)^{1/3}$, hence surface area $4\pi(3/4\pi)^{2/3}\approx4.5$.

Hope this helps. :>

I think this is the correct answer, or close to it.

Compute the  flux of the vector field $ \vec F=<x,y,z>$  across the unit sphere and the circumscribing cube. Note that $\vec F$ is the unit normal vector on both the sphere and each face of that cube. Thus
(iA)Flux across sphere = surface area of sphere.
(iiA) Flux across cube = surface area of cube.
But the divergence of $\vec F$ is the constant 3, so by the Divergence Theorem
(iB) Flux across unit sphere = 3 (Volume of unit sphere) and likewise
(iiB) Flux across cube = 3 (Volume of cube).
Thus (iA)/(iB) = 3 = ratio of surface area of sphere to volume of sphere; and likewise
(iiA)/(iiB) =3 = ratio of surface area of circumscribing cube to volume  of that cube.
This is precisely the equality of ratios that you asked to have explained.
Footnote. Note that the same argument can be used to prove that any convex polyhedron $P$ that circumscribes the unit sphere also satisfies the condition $Vol(P)/Area(P)=1/3$.  (Note that this is just the familiar relationship for the volume of a generalized cone in terms of the base area and perpendicular height). Thus in some sense we see that  the sphere is just a limiting case of what is true of polyhedral approximations.

Could you further explain what you're saying here? Both the surface areas and volumes of the unit cube and unit sphere are not the same, but it seems like you're claiming that they are...

I numbered the relevant equations so that you can see more clearly what ratios are proved to be equal. Note there is no claim that spheres and cubes have equal volumes.
